# Delete Elements from Array Multiple Times Based on Condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, web-scraping

Working on a web scraper where I pull basketball statistics from a page and format it in Node.  Here's an example of the data I'm working with in an "stats" array:

```
[
  'School1',    'ACC',        '35',   '34',         '33.2',
  '2.5',        '4.8',        '.515', '1.1',        '1.5',
  '.685',       '1.4',        '3.2',  '.434',       '0.5',
  '0.7',        '.692',       '0.7',  '2.7',        '3.4',
  '3.6',        '1.5',        '0.9',  '0.8',        '1.3',
  '6.8',        '',           '9.30', 'School2',    'Big 12',
  '22',         '22',         '36.7', '5.6',        '11.1',
  '.504',       '3.2',        '5.5',  '.592',       '2.4',
  '5.6',        '.419',       '1.7',  '2.0',        '.822',
  '1.5',        '4.4',        '5.9',  '6.5',        '2.5',
  '0.7',        '2.8',        '1.3',  '15.2',       '',
  '10.07',      'School1',    '',     '57',         '56',
  '34.6',       '3.7',        '7.2',  '.509',       '1.9',
  '3.1',        '.621',       '1.8',  '4.2',        '.426',
  '1.0',        '1.2',        '.775', '1.0',        '3.4',
  '4.4',        '4.7',        '1.9',  '0.8',        '1.6',
  '1.3',        '10.1',       '',     '9.68'
]
```

Each item in the array after a "SchoolX" data point represents season statistics for that specific school and year.  I only want to include the data from School2 in the array, here's what I've got for an initial loop to cut out unecessary info:

```
if (stats[0].includes("School2")) {
    playerObject.push({
        gp: stats[2],
        gs: stats[3],
        mpg: stats[4],
        fg: stats[7],
        tp: stats[9],
        ft: stats[11],
        rpg: stats[14],
        apg: stats[15],
        bpg: stats[16],
        spg: stats[17],
        ppg: stats[20]
    });
} else {
   // splice the input array of the first "season" data
    stats.splice(0, 28)
}
```

This successfully handles a scenario where the first "season" in the array was not at School2 and removes the data.  How can I create a loop to continue through the entire array and remove the values that don't correspond to seasons at School2 while keeping the rest of the data in the array?

Here's the expected output:

```
[
  'School2',    'Big 12',     '22',    22',         '36.7', 
  '5.6',        '11.1',       '.504', '3.2',        '5.5',  
  '.592',       '2.4',        '5.6',  '.419',       '1.7',  
  '2.0',        '.822',       '1.5',  '4.4',        '5.9',  
  '6.5',        '2.5',        '0.7',  '2.8',        '1.3',  
  '15.2',       '',           '10.07'
]
```

Only the data that corresponds to School2 remains in the array.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't understand how you're extracting the values you say you are...  According to the array you first posted, `stats[0]` is `'School1'`, `stats[2]` is `'35'`, `stats[3]` is `'34'`, etc.

Comment: @frandroid -  it's in the if/else.  If the first element of the "stats" array (first array above) matches School2, then I'm pushing statistics from those first 28 array elements to an object, otherwise I'm removing them from the array.

Comment: Do the name of all schools begin with `SchoolX`?

Comment: @JackFleeting - They do not, they will be real university names like "Virginia" or "Iowa State", I just anonymized them for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each school has indeed 28 elements, try something like this:

```
data =[your data from above];

const chunk = (arr, size) =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
    arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
  );
schools = chunk(data, 28);

for (school of schools) 
  if (school[0]=="School2")
    console.log(school);
```

Note: the `chunk` part is [borrowed from here.](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/fundamental/javascript-fundamental-exercise-265.php)